# will <frameset> work with HTML5?

Tags: html, w3c, frameset-iframe

I have these webapplications build in old style HTML, including [framesets] to speed up the GUI of the administration.

Its not accessable by SEO etc. so thats not the issue here, it was all based on speed and minimizing reload at the time.

Now we would like to transform these applications and have begun to investigate HTML5 for the purpose.

Ofcause there is AJAX and db-storage etc. to speed up the interface with the new standards, but our question is really:

is IFRAMES and FRAMESETS going to be removed from the HTML5 standard or will it be "allowed" but "less appriciated" ?

Does anyone know whats going to happend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The frameset and frame elements are **obsolete** in HTML5.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features

The iframe element is valid.

Note that HTML5 still requires browsers to support frames and framesets as per Oded's link, but they are not valid for authors to use on web pages.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, framesets will work, they are part of the current HTML5 [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#frames-and-framesets).

So is [`iFrame`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-iframe-element.html#the-iframe-element).

As for your question on will they be deprecated or removed all together?

Frames and framesets **should not be used** in HTML5 as they have been [obsoleted](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html).